# Subreport Table data scope issue SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, iif

I'm trying to select data from other datasets to include in my table. This is the expression I have so far:

```
=iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=1
, (First(Fields!NumbBreaker.Value, "sp_Permit11"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=3
, (First(Fields!MoldProd.Value, "sp_PermitASMoldProd"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value =4
, (First(Fields!MoldProd.Value, "sp_PermitASMoldProd"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value =5
, (First(Fields!Thermal.Value, "sp_PermitThermalSand"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=6
, ((First(Fields!Steel20T.Value, "sp_Permit11")) + (First(Fields!Steel9T.Value, "sp_Permit11")) + (First(Fields!Ductile.Value, "sp_Permit11")))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=7
, ((First(Fields!Steel20T.Value, "sp_Permit11")) + (First(Fields!Steel9T.Value, "sp_Permit11")))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=8
, (First(Fields!IMF.Value, "sp_Permit11"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value=9
, (First(Fields!Ductile.Value, "sp_Permit11"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 10
, (First(Fields!DM1.Value, "sp_PermitDM1"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 12
, (First(Fields!Zircon.Value, "sp_PermitZircon"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 14
, (First(Fields!CMN.Value, "sp_PermitCMN"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 15
, (First(Fields!A270.Value, "sp_Permit270"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value= 16
, (First(Fields!A290.Value, "sp_Permit290"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 17
, (First(Fields!CM8.Value, "sp_PermitCM8"))
,iif(ReportItems!ID.Value = 20
, (First(Fields!NT.Value, "sp_PermitNT")),"")))))))))))))))
```

How can I do this without using the `First`? The first is only bringing in the first value but without it I get:

> Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current
>   dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope

Comment: Why don't you want to use "first"?   What are you trying to do?

Comment: Because there are 3 rows of values that i want to display, not just the first one.

Comment: So depending on the value of `ReportItems!ID.Value` you want the table to show the 3 rows from one of the various datasets?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: The only way I know to do what you want is to combine all your datasets into one.

Comment: I was hoping to get away with not having to try that. The stored procedures are already pretty long and combining them all will not be pretty.

Comment: Okay that got me the correct information I needed!!! But it also gave me another problem. The first time the subreport load it gives me 3 rows of data just fine, the next load of the subreport gives me 6 rows, and then 9 and so forth. It repeats the correct 3 rows of data over and over. Any clue what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select data from another dataset without specifying which data you want. This is why you need the `First` function - it is the easiest way to specify what to select from the other dataset.

However, there are other ways to select the data that you want. I'll assume that each dataset has the unique `ID` field so we can use the `Lookup` function. Also, let's change from using `IIF` and use `Switch` instead as it is a bit more convenient for this sort of statement.

Now your expression will look like this:

```
=Switch(
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 1, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!NumbBreaker.Value, "sp_Permit11"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 3, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!MoldProd.Value, "sp_PermitASMoldProd"),
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 4, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!MoldProd.Value, "sp_PermitASMoldProd"),
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 5, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Thermal.Value, "sp_PermitThermalSand"),
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 6, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Steel20T.Value, "sp_Permit11") + Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Steel9T.Value, "sp_Permit11") + Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Ductile.Value, "sp_Permit11"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 7, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Steel20T.Value, "sp_Permit11") + Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Steel9T.Value, "sp_Permit11"),
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 8, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!IMF.Value, "sp_Permit11"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 9, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Ductile.Value, "sp_Permit11"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 10, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!DM1.Value, "sp_PermitDM1"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 12, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Zircon.Value, "sp_PermitZircon"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 14, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!CMN.Value, "sp_PermitCMN"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 15, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!A270.Value, "sp_Permit270"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 16, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!A290.Value, "sp_Permit290"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 17, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!CM8.Value, "sp_PermitCM8"), 
  ReportItems!ID.Value = 20, Lookup(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!NT.Value, "sp_PermitNT"), 
  True, "")
```

So we look up the value we want in the other dataset based on a unique key in the current dataset and return whichever field we want from the other dataset. The `True, ""` bit at the end is effectively the `else` condition - it is what is returned if no other condition is met.

Comment: Using LookUp wont work for me. The ReportItems!ID.Value is a Parameter that is being sent in from the main report. So based on that parameter I need to fill that table with the information from one of my datasets. The datasets each contain 3 rows of information. I really just started working with reports so I hope this is making sense.